# How can I center a text in R via Latex

Tags: latex

I want to center the statement "Hypothesis: \alpha_4 = 0"

just above bold "reject and dont reject"  expressions. How can I do this ?

```
$$
\begin{matrix} 
              Hypothesis: \alpha_4 = 0     \\
 \color{#e64173}{Hypothesis:\beta_4 = 0} & \textbf{Do not Reject} & \textbf{Reject} \\
 \color{#e64173}{Do \ not\ Reject} & \text{Accept Both C and D} & \text{Accept D, Reject C} \\
 \color{#e64173}{Reject} & \text{Accept C, Reject D} & \text{Reject Both C and D}
 
\end{matrix}
$$
```

Comment: what does this question have to do with R?  Maybe you want this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131867/using-multicolumn-in-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with kableExtra.

I'm not sure this is possible using a matrix within an equation block.

Assuming the requirement is to present the formated information in a tabular format in a rmarkdown pdf_document, this might be of use:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```
````

Create a data frame with the text and format text for individual cells.

````
```{r, include=FALSE}


    df <- data.frame(a = c("Hypothesis: $beta_4$ = 0", "Do not Reject", "Reject"),
                     b = c("Do not Reject", "Accept Both C and D", "Accept D, Reject C"),
                     c = c("Reject", "Reject D", "Reject Both C and D"))
    
    df[1, 2:3] = cell_spec(df[1, 2:3], bold  = TRUE)

    
```
````

Format the table with a bit of help from:
https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/413 for getting rid of the horizontal lines.

````
```{r, results='asis'}

kbl(df,
    col.names = NULL,
    align = "ccc",
    booktabs = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Hypothesis: $alpha_4$ = 0 " = 2 ),
                   line = FALSE, 
                   escape = FALSE) %>% 
  column_spec(1, color = "#e64173") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position", position = "center") %>%
  sub("\\\\toprule", "", .) %>%
  sub("\\\\bottomrule", "", .)


```
````

Which results in  this table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is  just above the "do not reject expression".

Comment: Now it is above the reject expression :) I guess there is no solution for this, It automatically puts it above one of the three expressions as we add the ampersand

Comment: Just to be clear. Do you want the hypotheses text to be over column 2 and 3 i.e. like a merged column? Rather than over either column 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes exactly I wanted this.

Comment: Updated answer with a kableExtra solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I didn't know about this, I will use it. Have a good day.